# Adding a hyperlink into noty alert

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have recently come across noty as a jquery plugin as I do not have much knowledge on javascript, I came across a problem when adding hyperlinks into the popup. I tried using the document.write for javascript but it does not work. I hope I can get some help here.

http://needim.github.com/noty/

My notification:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
noty({"text":"You have a new message."})
</script>
```

I have only added the part that displays the message to make it more direct. I tried to source for information all over google but couldn't find anything related. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to add a link to the [`noty`](http://needim.github.com/noty/) popup?  Have you tried just adding a link in the `text`?  `noty({text:' This is a link to <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'});`

Comment: Yes I have tried. It doesn't work that way. But my format may be wrong. I will give it a try again because of all the quotes in the link I may have gotten it wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have used the wrong quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
<a href="#">LINK</a>.
```

It will work.

Example:

```
noty({text: 'NOTIFY WITH LINK < a href="http://example.com">EXAMPLE< /a >', 
       custom: {container: $('#notycontainer')}});
```

Comment: while this does work, what about <router-link>s? (sorry for digging up this ancient thread)

Answer (score 0):

Rocket is correct. I just tried this with the proper quoting on the noty site.

```
Hi! I'm an example text. When I grow up I want to be a <a href="#">test </a> noty message.
```

Works fine. You have to use double quotes when inside single quotes and vice versa, or you can escape the quotes with \